# How can I center the output from some javascript?

Tags: javascript

On my site, I'm using the following advertising tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
GA_googleFillSlot("Skyscraper");
</script>
```

How can I get that "Skyscraper" to be centered, rather than range left (everything else in that zone is properly range left, but the skyscraper is narrower than the column, so I need it to center)?

Comment: Try wrapping a div with a text-align: center around the script.

Comment: @Justin That will only work if it outputs an inline element. I had the feeling this would output an `iframe` or something like that (though it may be an `img`).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what that outputs, but you might be able to do...

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    GA_googleFillSlot("Skyscraper");
    </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: This was my thought on it too. The other is to look at what GA_googleFillSlot returns and then follow that function call with js code to apply the css styling to achieve the centering on what ever html is returned by the GA_googleFillSlot call. (A quick google suggests it creates a div with the id: google_ads_div_Skyscraper)

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. The <div> code doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: The GA_googleFillSlot returns an ad from Doubleclick for Publishers.

Comment: Here's what worked. It's a slight amendment on @alex's answer:

    <div style="width: 120px; margin: 0 auto 15px;">

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    GA_googleFillSlot("Skyscraper");
    </script> 
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="ad_container">
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      GA_googleFillSlot("Skyscraper");
   </script> 
</div>
```

and

```
.ad_container div {
   text-align:center;
}
```

worked nicely as the Google ad has "display: inline-table;" on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **max-content**

```
<div style="width: max-content; margin: 0 auto 0;">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    GA_googleFillSlot("Skyscraper");
    </script> 
 </div>
```